# optimal number of mongodb entities (administration/devops)

Tags: mongodb

I intend to check mongodb performance by running an application on 8 servers.

-1. here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/ I read,

> In production deployments, you must deploy **exactly three config server
>   instances**, each running on different servers to assure good uptime and
>   data safety. In test environments, you can run all three instances on
>   a single server.

What if I want to use optimally the resources of 8 servers (+ 1 dedicated server for the application)? Do I start 1 config server instance per server?

-2. I see here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/
that using replica sets with 3 mongod instances (with each mongod instance on a different server) is the way to go? Is this the optimal scenario when it comes to having 8 servers?

-3. How many replica sets would I use when I have 8 servers? 1 per server (8 servers == 8 replica sets == 3 mongod instances per server from different replica sets)?

-4. Is there any best practices documentation regarding optimization of this type?

Kind Regards,
Despot

Answer (score 1):

> What if I want to use optimally the resources of 8 servers (+ 1 dedicated server for the application)?

That's not an optimal way to plan, there is no way you know that you NEED 7 shards for your data.

> Do I start 1 config server instance per server?

No, you are hardcoded to three.

> Is this the optimal scenario when it comes to having 8 servers?

No, it is the minimum, you would ideally want more members, especially one bridging partitions; ensuring all the while you have an odd number of node on one side of your parition to ensure CAP.

Normally your replica set would consist of at least one extra member designed for backups, normally using a `slaveDelay` of maybe a day.

> How many replica sets would I use when I have 8 servers?

Assuming (guessing) you want to use 7 shards you would have 7 replica sets, one per shard.

> 3 mongod instances per server from different replica sets

That would be a bad idea. You do not want to place the replica members on the same server as each other, you might as well be using no replication.

I would seriously plan more and check if you really need 7 shards, I highly doubt it.

Comment: "That's not an optimal way to plan, there is no way you know that you NEED 7 shards for your data." It would be 8 shards at least (1 per server). And yes, the bigger the amount of resources the better your app will fly! That's the whole point of scaling, right?! The map-reduce flow we go faster when you use 8 servers, that to use 3 servers.

Comment: "That would be a bad idea. You do not want to place the replica members on the same server as each other, you might as well be using no replication." I never said that the 3 mongod instances (that would live on the server) will be from the same replica set. 3 mongod instances from 3 different replica sets. So as I see it there will be a min of 8 replica sets (with 1 primary + 2 backups per replica set). The question now is, is it better to have more replica sets?

Comment: @despot so the application server would have a shard? That sounds...dangerous. And no, your assumption about "the bigger the amount of resources the better your app will fly!" is not true, if you are using only 1/3 of those resources you are still using only 1/3 and in fact having a sharded set might be slower than a single server setup that you could have, also if you want you app to fly you might wanna look into optimising the application workflow, if you need map reduce to finish quickly you are doing something wrong

Comment: @despot Unless each physical server has enough power to definitely handle multiple MongoDBs (in which case you don't need sharding) then that would be a bad idea to put more than one mongod on a server

Comment: "so the application server would have a shard?" "(+ 1 dedicated server for the application)" I will have a 9th server.

Comment: @despot ok that detail confused me, I thoght you had 7 servers plus a application server